# How do I refer to an attribute that contains a colon? (Selenium/python/xpath/css)

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, laravel-livewire

[example html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c23S5.png)

Every field has the same property apart from the wire: model attribute, but I can't link to it as I don't have enough experience to write the correct selector.
I would be very grateful if you can help me put together the correct selection.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Do you mind sharing? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: According to these selectors, selenium does not find elements: 'input[wire:model="lastName"]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:-

```
textValues = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='space-y-2']/input")
for e in textValues:
    print(e.get_attribute("wire:model"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem, for which I am very grateful to you.                         
`textValues = self.browser.find_elements(*ABITUR.wire_model)`
`for e in textValues:`
    `if e.get_attribute("wire:model") == 'middleName':`
      ` if clear != (None):`
        `  e.clear()`
      ` e.send_keys(middleName)`
      ` break`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS Selector that should work to grab the 'lastName' element, for example:

```
'input[wire:model="lastName"]'
```

[Here's some hopefully helpful documentation on writing selectors.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is the first thing I tried before asking a question. In my case, this appeal does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.grid > div:first-child input {
   /* this would target Last Name */
 }

.grid > div:nth-child(3) input {
   /* replace 3 with whatever you want. 1 would target Last Name, 2 would target First Name, 3 would target Middle Name
 }
```

Comment: This solution is not unique in my case, since there are about 27 such fields, and they change if the parameter is changed.